# setData Issue in CKEDITOR

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEDITOR to get input from user,I am saving generated HTML in database, i am modifying my html with following php methods before saving in database:

```
trim(htmlspecialchars(Generated HTML from CKEDITOR))
```

For some reason i have to pull html from database and set it to CKEDITOR with setData, I m using following code,

`<script>CKEDITOR.replace('desc2').setData(\''.htmlspecialchars_decode($data6['html']).'\', function(){this.checkDirty();});</script>`

ISSUE: When html is very basic and simple without line breaks or images, then it works fine but when i put line breaks and images in CKEDITOR,it shows exeption SyntaxError: unterminated string literal .Please replay to sort out this issue.

Comment: I honestly can't make heads nor tails out of your example code...

Comment: In short i am having line breaks in my html when i save in database.Those line breaks causing break my ckeditor when i reassign html to ckeditor by following code."<script>CKEDITOR.replace(\'desc'.$slide_no.'\').setData(\''.htmlspecialchars_decode($data6['html']).'\', function(){this.checkDirty();});</script>"

Comment: Ok, consider what happens if a character sequence that PHP would consider an escaped character (or worse still, a non escaped quote) in that line of text. it breaks the string you're trying to put into the `.setData` function.

Comment: You would end up with something like `'<img src='banana.png'></img>'` (see those matching single quotes? those are the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Escape sequences occurring in the `$data6['html']` variable when you've run it through `htmlspecialchars_decode`, combined with string concatenation are possibly causing your problems.

In order to fix that, try staying away from string concatenation in cases like this.
(i have no idea if this code will work for you exactly as is, but you get the idea :

```
$ckEditorContent = htmlspecialchars_decode($data6['html']);
CKEDITOR.replace('desc2').setData(htmlspecialchars_decode($ckEditorContent), function(){this.checkDirty();});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all replies,My problem solved with following code.

```
<script>CKEDITOR.replace('desc2').setData(json_encode($data6['html']), function(){this.checkDirty();});</script>
```